# Which website/database architecture to use, many HTTP requests + mediafile uploads?

Tags: php, database, performance, architecture, scalability

I am starting to redesign my current website project and would like to replace it by an architecture that can help me scale easily and has good performance.

Our prototype is running on a PHP Framework (CAKEPHP) + mySQL Server + 1ghz virutal server WIN2008 Server (feasibility test).

This system will not go online since it would not be able to meet the requirements.

- Should be able to handle LOTS of HTTP-Requests per second ( scalability via hadoop maybe ? )  may become a bottleneck.
- Should be able to handle many simultaneous uploads per minute ( mediafiles ) on the filesystem read and write + Media conversion ( Atm something like LAME encoder, are there faster tools? ) => bottleneck
- Database gets many QUERIES per second ( somehow using clustering SQL Cluster or any cheaper product available? )
- USE of CDN for static mediafiles
- UNIX System?
- should file compression be used ? CPU vs Bandwidth cost?

**The scary part are the HTTP Requests and mediaupload & converter.**

I started researching on www.highscalability.com for some good ebooks and would appreciate if some pro´s out here could give me some advice on this our helpful links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at those books:

- [High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End
  Engineers](http://rcm-de.amazon.de/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=semanticblog-21&o=3&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0596529309) (Steve Souders)
- [Even Faster Web Sites: Performance Best
  Practices for Web Developers](http://rcm-de.amazon.de/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=semanticblog-21&o=3&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0596522304) (Steve Souders)
- [Building Scalable Web Sites](http://rcm-de.amazon.de/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=semanticblog-21&o=3&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0596102356) (Cal Henderson)
- Use Linux as operating system,
- Nginx as webserver (serveral instances
  can be loadbalanced) Nginx can handle a lot
  of http requests!
- Redis for caching.
- Solr or Sphinx for searching.
- You could use a [mongdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413115/is-gridfs-fast-and-reliable-enough-for-production) to store the files or take a look at [mogilefs](http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/)

For media conversions you could try node.js:
http://www.benfarrell.com/2012/06/14/morph-your-media-with-node-js/.

There are a few conversion(?) libraries at github:
http://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame

Perhaps a few Servers with [gearman](http://gearman.org/) installed could handle the conversion as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. use Linux as Centos, debian no windows
2. use Pseudo-static
3. use cache
4. if the Browsing speed is not fast you should need CDN
5. if you have enough money more CPUs are perfect
6. you can use some Traffic monitoring software to judge wheather need
   more Bandwidth or not