# Gridfs-Nginx vs Gridfs from tornado

Tags: nginx, tornado, gridfs

i've found [this benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413115/is-gridfs-fast-and-reliable-enough-for-production) but it is old (2010).

is there any one who made a benchmark using:

- Serving the picture using [Nginx-GridFS](https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs)

VS

- Serving the picture from [Tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado)

Answer (score 0):

We've been serving ~400 rps from mongodb using our https://github.com/unistorage/gridfs-serve

Never benchmarked it, but it's okay for our needs.